# Modifying Headline in Beamer Berlin

Tags: beamer, themes

I am trying to remove the blank space under the navigation menu and above the frame title. I can remove the entire header by including

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
```

but I do not want to lose the navigation menu.

```
\documentclass[slidestop,mathserif,12pt,xcolor=pdftex,table]{beamer}
\usetheme[compress]{Berlin}
% Changes background to correct colors
\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{HTML}{B01E24} 

\usefoottemplate{\vbox{
\tinycolouredline{structure!25}
{\color{white}\textbf{\insertshortauthor\hfill
\insertshorttitle}}
}}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{comment}

\author{Name}
\institute{Place}
\title{Class}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Section 1}

\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\begin{enumerate}[]
\item Item 1
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That place shows the current subsection.

This is the original headline definition, in `beamerouterthememiniframes.sty`:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{miniframes theme}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

To remove the part showing the subsection title, remove everything connected to the subsection, that is between `\ifbeamer@theme@subsection%` and `\fi%`:

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

Add this to your preamble.
Result:

[image: Result]

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Perfect! I didn't recognize that is where the current subsection titles were displayed since I had not labeled them. Thanks.